# Overriding functions (from two abstract base classes) that differ only by their return value

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I want to create a class that implements two interfaces that have functions with a same name that differ only by their return values. How can I do this correctly?

```
template<class T>
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual T Method() = 0;
};

class Derived : public IBase<int>, public IBase<char> {
public:
    int _value;

    virtual int IBase<int>::Method();
    virtual char IBase<char>::Method();
};

int Derived::Method() {
    return _value;
}

char Derived::Method() {
    return _value;
}
```

Here are the errors that I get:

```
error C2555: 'Derived::Method: overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'IBase<int>::Method

error C2556: 'int Derived::Method(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'char Derived::Method(void)'

error C2371: 'Derived::Method: redefinition; different basic types

error C2084: function 'char Derived::Method(void)' already has a body
```

In C# it's pretty easy to do this without any ambiguities using nearly same syntax (called explicit interface implementation):

```
class Derived : IBase<int>, IBase<char> {
    int _value;

    int IBase<int>.Method() {
        return _value;
    }

    char IBase<char>.Method();
        return _value;
    }
};
```

Explicitly implementations are private and thus cannot be used directly on variables of class `Derived`. They are still very usable though as you can cast the `Derived` to one of the interfaces to use the implementation:

```
var d = new Derived();
((IBase<int>)d).Method();
```

This can be rather useful. A class can implement ICanConvertTo many times to enable different conversions.

Comment: By the way GCC gives different errors: http://ideone.com/3f0ZVG (`cannot declare member function ‘IBase<int>::Method’ within ‘Derived’` and the same for `char` instead of `int`, then `no ‘int Derived::Method()’ member function declared in class ‘Derived’`  and the same for `char` instead of `int`)

Comment: @gx_ Did you delete your comment? I thought it was quite useful.

Comment: Yes I did, because I realized that it was actually not the same question (your return types are different). Anyway, since you asked =) this question is somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398409/c-inherit-from-multiple-base-classes-with-the-same-virtual-function-name (after template instantiation, `IBase<int>` and `IBase<char>` are two different unrelated classes)

Comment: I think that you were right that the return type difference doesn't matter. What matters is that the name and signature is the same (bad), but the fully qualified name and slot are different (could have saved me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With virtual in Derived

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class IBase
{
    public:
    virtual T method() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class WrapBase : public IBase<T>
{
    protected:
    virtual T do_method(T*) = 0;

    public:
    virtual T method() {
        return do_method((T*)0);
    }
};

class Derived : public WrapBase<char>, public WrapBase<int>
{
    protected:
    virtual char do_method(char*) { return 'A'; };
    virtual int do_method(int*) { return 1; };
};
```

Removing virtual in Derived - **Thanks to DyP**:

```
include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class IBase
{
    public:
    virtual T method() = 0;
};

template<typename D, typename T>
class WrapBase : public IBase<T>
{
    public:
    virtual T method();
};

class Derived : public WrapBase<Derived, char>, public WrapBase<Derived, int>
{
    friend class WrapBase<Derived, char>;
    friend class WrapBase<Derived, int>;

    protected:
    char do_method(char*) { return 'A'; };
    int do_method(int*) { return 1; };
};

template<typename D, typename T>
inline T WrapBase<D, T>::method() {
    return static_cast<D*>(this)->do_method((T*)0);
}
```

Test:

```
int main () {
    Derived d;
    IBase<char>& c = d;
    IBase<int>& i = d;
    std::cout << c.method() << " != " << i.method() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Mixing static and dynamic polymorphism might be a bad design.

Comment: Interesting! What are you considering static polymorphism here?

Comment: @Ark-kun The template

Comment: My goal is for the solution to be fully static and "inlinable". And I think that your solution manages that.

Comment: You could use the CRTP (at least) in `WrapBase` to get rid of the second virtual function call. With C++11 support, I think a `final` specifier could also help for `WrapBase::method`. `do_method` can be `private`.

Comment: Note: My suggestion makes it impossible to override the `do_method` functions is classes derived from `Derived` (and you can't override the original `method` either).

Comment: (Unless you use a fancy CRTP that passes the most-derived type up in the hierarchy to `WrapBase`.)

Answer (score 2):

Function can not differ only by return value, because the compiler has no way to distinguish them. Consider:

```
long x;
Derived d;
x = d.Method();
```

both the `char` and the `int` variant are possible to convert to an `long` - which one should it use?

Edit:
If you want to define conversions, the typical case is to define a cast-operator, e.g.

```
class X 
{
     float x;
   public:
     X(float f) : x(f) {}
     operator int() { return static_cast<int>(x); }
     operator char() { return static_cast<char>(x); }
     float getX() { return x; }
};
```

and then call it as:

```
X x(65.3);
int y = x;
char z = x;

cout << "x.f=" << x.getF() << " as char:" << z << " as int:" << y << endl;
```

Comment: I doubt this. I've heard that there is a way to explicitly call one of the functions. Something like `d.IBase<int>::Method();`

Comment: Calling `d.Method();` is ambiguous and is rightfully disabled. But this shouldn't prevent me from implementing the methods. I can call it explicitly like `((IBase<int>)d).Method()`. Just like I can do in C#.

Comment: @Ark-kun Are you asking about c++ or c#?

Comment: You have noticed that the compiler is not complaining where you are USING the method, but where you are declaring it, right?

Comment: @BЈовић C++. I can easily do this in C# (see updated question), but I need to do this in C++.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes, I did. That's why I was skeptical about your answer which focused on potential usage problems, while I was asking about declaration.

Comment: The reason the standard disallows "only return type difference" is that it's not possible for the compiler to determine which one of the functions it should use. I tried to explain WHY the compiler won't allow it with an example. Since the compiler gives the error for "You have two functions that differ only by return value". I have edited in a suggestion for a solution - but depending on what you are trying to do, I'm not sure whether that will work for you or not.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I still don't see how "it's not possible for the compiler to determine which one of the functions it should use", because I'm not using any of the functions. The C++ compiler does just fine in other similar cases like the conversion operators.

Comment: I want my classes to have multiple conversion functions. I cannot use operators since the functions have arguments. Something like `instance.ReadElementAs<Color>(10)`, `instance.ReadElementAs<int>(10)`. Each class has a limited set of hand-written converters.

Comment: @Ark-kun: Did you read my latest comment: I said "The standard forbids this because it wouldn't be possible for the compiler to determine which function you want to use". You may want to google for "C++ function return type overload" or some such. 
Here's one such question here, which suggests essentially the same answer I gave:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226144/overload-a-c-function-according-to-the-return-value

Comment: @Ark-kun: Then I'm afraid you'll have to call the functions different names, or put them into different classes, or something like that.

Comment: If I call the functions differently, then I cannot select them based on the template parameter.

Comment: I've read your comment, but it's a bit hard to digest the "it wouldn't be possible for the compiler to determine which function you want to use" since the compiler that is able to do this impossible thing sits right before me.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand you. What did you mean by "use" when you said "it's not possible for the compiler to determine which one of the functions it should use"? Use what? Where? How?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the standard forbids "only return type difference in functions". As I'm not a member of the C++ standards committee, I'm not 100% sure why it is so. However, I've read the suggestion that "the compiler can't tell which one of the functions you want". It doesn't really matter what the standards committee had as a reason, it's still not allowed to have a function that has ONLY return type as difference between functions - that is certain, and that is why the compiler complains about the function declarations.

Comment: "the compiler can't tell which one of the functions you want" There are 3 places where functions are mentioned: declaration, definition and calls. I wasn't sure which one you meant.

Comment: "it's still not allowed to have a function that has ONLY return type as difference between functions". `operator int();`, `operator char();`...

Comment: Those are not functions, they are specific conversion operators. Please don't shoot the messenger...

Comment: Sorry. Really sorry! I was being excessively aggressive. I should never do this. That was probably because different C++ issues kept me awake till 15 P.M. hours of the next day today (and consumed previous 2 weeks of my life). And that's just porting a small close-to-metal C# prototype that only took some hours to write. >_<

Comment: One more thing =) You can have a whole lot of functions with the same name and signature using templates. Template methods with 0, 1, 2 etc. template parameters are independent and can coexist. So, templates give us infinity*a_lot functions that differ only by the return values. Too bad I actually only want a few of them.

Comment: It's OK, I understand it's frustrating - I just felt a bit like the messenger carrying bad news, and being shot at for delivering bad new... Different number of arguments is enough of a difference. But I don't think you can have templates with the same template parameter and different return types (not 100% sure tho').

Comment: @MatsPetersson You are correct, even template functions cannot have the only difference be return type. In C++, function names are mangled with the parameter types and not the return type, so functions that differ only on the return types would mangle to the same symbol for the linker, causing confusion. So, C++ disallows overloading on return types. Btw, `operator int()` and `operator char()` have different names. `operator` is part of the function name. It can be omitted because of some syntactic sugar rules.

Answer (score 1):

Returned value type is not part of the function (method) signature.

So your two methods are seen as the same method (so the redefinition error).

So you can't do what you want. your method should have different signature.

Comment: The functions have a big difference - they are from different base classes. One can say that they have different names: `IBase<int>::Method()` and `IBase<char>::Method()`.

Comment: Currently, the function *are* in Derivated. If you give implementation to IBase<int>::Method() and remove declaration of Derivated::Method(), you may call derivated.IBase<int>::Method(), but you can't redefine Derivated::Method()

Comment: @Jarod42 by the way it's Derived, not "Derivated" :)