# How to override base classes' virtual functions that have identical names in multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have two base classes `B1` and `B2`, and a class `D` that derives from both B1 and B2 as follows:

```
class B1 {
public:
  // ...
  virtual void foo() final { cout << "Hello, B1\n"; }
};

class B2 {
public:
  // ...
  virtual void foo() { cout << "Good riddance, B2!\n"; }
};

class D :public B1, public B2 {
  // ...
};
```

In designing the class `D`, I want to override the member function called `foo()` from B2; however, `foo()` in B1 is marked `final` and prevents me from overriding `foo()` in B2. What is the best approach to override `foo()` from B2?

Comment: Isn't saying a function is virtual and final contradicting itself? Just curious :P

Comment: @Ediac, `B1` could have a base class that defines `foo` to be virtual. In that case, `B1`'s `foo` is virtual whether it's marked that way or not.

Comment: to avoid this confusion multiple inheritance is not allowed in languages like java and c#

Comment: @Ediac, I know, like why declare a base class's member function virtual and final? :) I tried to make the question as clear as I could by simplifying the bases. B1 and B2 would be in their own respective class hierarchy where B1's `foo()` was basically declared not to be overridden further down in its hierarchy, but had I wanted to use some other features from B1 and also override `foo()` from B2, how would I be able to do that since B1's `foo()` conflicts with B2's `foo()'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think what you want to do is possible in the manner you've shown in the question. From N3337, *§10.3/2 [class.virtual]*

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides `Base::vf`. ...

`D::foo` matches all those criteria for `B1::foo` and `B2::foo`, hence it overrides *both*. And since `B1::foo` is `final`, the code is ill-formed.

One workaround is to introduce an extra level of inheritance. Define a class, say `D2`, that derives from `B2` and overrides `B2::foo`. Then `D` can derive from `B1` and `D2` instead.

```
class D2 : public B2{
public:
  virtual void foo() override { cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};

class D :public B1, public D2 
{};

D d;
// d.foo();    // error - ambiguous

D2& d2 = d;
d2.foo();   // calls D2::foo
B2& b2 = d;
b2.foo();   // calls D2::foo

B1& b1 = d;
b1.foo();   // calls B1::foo
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20b3ab598fe7dfb5)

Comment: I like your solution, it does answer the question as I posed it. Not to stray too far from this topic, but in a design sense, this solution would actually bury this small issue as the hierarchy grows, and the problem would still remain if someone wanted to override `foo()` from `D` or any of D's sub-classes. I wonder if there might be a better solution that might allow further (and potentially safe) derivations using D as a base.

Comment: @Region You're right that this solution just kicks the can down the road, if you want to derive from `D` and override `foo` you have the same problem again. Unfortunately, I don't see a way around that. I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18400950/241631) to a similar question, and that suggests the same workaround as I have. Maybe you should post another question, linking to this one, and ask specifically for an alternate solution.