# Weird syntax when overriding virtual functions

Tags: c++, syntax, overriding, language-lawyer

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399065/455304), I was surprised enough to try out for myself if it really works as described:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class C : public A, public B {
public:
    virtual void foo();
};

void C::foo(){
  std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
}
void C::A::foo(){
  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
void C::B::foo(){
  std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    C c;
    static_cast<A*>(&c)->foo();
    static_cast<B*>(&c)->foo();
    c.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I really did not think that it was possible to override a virtual method from two different base classes, that have the same name and signature. And, as I expected, above program prints:

```
C
C
C
```

So the answer is wrong - as I felt from the start. Surprising part is: why does my gcc accept this syntax: `void C::A::foo(){`? I could not find anything on what that could mean. Is this a gcc bug/feature? Is it some obscure standard C++ syntax? Or am I misinterpreting the situation completely?

EDIT:

It seems that `void C::A::foo(){}` is just a definition for `A::foo` in this context. But why? Is this GCC bug? Or is this somehow permitted by the standard? If so, is it specific rule for this kind of thing, or some kind of generic clause (say: if an identifier doesn't make sense - like 'C::A::foo', then compiler is free to do what it wants).

Comment: Note that if you do `c.A::foo()` it will write "A".

Comment: @ChrisDrew This syntax means a static (non-virtual) call to specific version of `foo`. Combined with my edit, it is clear why it writes "A". But it doesn't change VMT entry for `foo` in any way.

Comment: It's `A`'s *injected-class-name*, which `C` inherited.

Comment: As you are interesting in `C::A::foo` syntax, you may remove all extra stuff (as pure virtual with implementation) to something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d5bc10e4ed20b92).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the fact that `C::A::foo` defines `A::foo` is due to the *injected-class-name*.

> `N3337 [class]/2:` A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the class-name is seen.
>   The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the injected-class-name.
>   For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name. [...]

Since `A` is a base class of `C` and the name `A` is injected into the scope of `A`, `A` is also visible from `C`.

Given the above, we can do horribly perverse things like:

```
void C::C::C::A::A::A::foo(){
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3581c111288b4a66)

Comment: Ouch... so this syntax has nothing to do with overriding virtual functions - as I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Interestingly enough,

```
void C::A::foo(){
  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
```

defines `A::foo()` (you can provide an implementation for a pure virtual function if you want to). You can check that this is really the case by adding an additional definition:

```
void A::foo(){
  std::cout << "Base A" << std::endl;
}
void C::A::foo(){
  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
```

GCC will report a multiple definition error. This probably makes sense, because you can look at `C::A` as a name alias for `A`.

In terms of what the standard says, I'm currently struggling to find the exact definition of when this is appropriate in the sea of standardese, but I can see a related example in [Paragraph 3.4.3.1.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf):

```
struct A { A(); };
struct B: public A { B(); };
A::A() { }
B::B() { }
B::A ba; // object of type A // <-- here
A::A a; // error, A::A is not a type name
struct A::A a2; // object of type A
```

The example is to do with constructor resolution, but constructor is ultimately a method, so my guess is that GCC used the same mechanism for every scope resolution.

Comment: "This probably makes sense, because you can look at `C::A` as a name alias for `A`" - Can you really? Is it somehow mandated by the standard?

Comment: I already accepted another answer, as it provided better standard citation. This has little to do with constructor resolution. It is because `A` is injected into `A` scope, and thus into `C` scope as well.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it. I meant that the example was to do with constructor resolution and that I don't know which is the actual rule applied in the example. I'll clarify this

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio compiler (2008) does not allow

```
void C::A::foo(){
  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
void C::B::foo(){
  std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
```

but only

```
void A::foo(){
  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
void B::foo(){
  std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
```

as it is completely valid to provide a definition for pure virtual methods.

> "Effective C++" Meyers mentions a reason for a pure virtual function
>   to have a body: Derived classes that implement this pure virtual
>   function may call this implementation smwhere in their code. If part
>   of the code of two different derived classes is similar then it makes
>   sense to move it up in the hierarchy, even if the function should be
>   pure virtual.

See [here (forum.codeguru.com)](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?356281-C-why-pure-virtual-function-has-definition-Please-look-into-sample-code-here).

A pure virtual function cannot be called dynamically, but statically:

```
C c;
static_cast<A*>(&c)->foo(); // prints C
static_cast<B*>(&c)->foo(); // prints C, dynamic dispatch
c.foo();                    // prints C, dynamic dispatch
c.A::foo();                 // prints A, static dispatch
c.B::foo();                 // prints B, static dispatch
```

Explanation:

> When you call a virtual function using its fully-qualified name (the
>   class-name followed by “::”), the compiler does not use the virtual
>   call mechanism, but instead uses the same mechanism as if you called a
>   non-virtual function. Said another way, it calls the function by name
>   rather than by slot-number. So if you want code within derived class
>   Der to call Base::f(), that is, the version of f() defined in its base
>   class Base, you should write:

```
void Derived::f()
{ Base::f(); }
```

See [here (isocpp.org)](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#fully-qualified-calls-to-base).

Comment: From another answer it seems that `void C::A::foo(){}` should be allowed. Is injected-class-name some new (C++11) addition? If so then I wouldn't expect to see it in MSVC2008 - but if this feature is older, then it is MSVC bug.

Comment: At the very least the injected-class-name is in C++03, also at [class]/2.