# C++ multiple inheritance from different abstract bases with same pure virtual method

Tags: c++

Imagine

```
class A
{
  public: virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B
{
  public: virtual void f() = 0;
};

class C : public A,B
{
  public: virtual void f()
  { // implementation here
  }
};

C c();
```

That seems to compile.
(Didn't try to compile my example, but a more complex real life scenario).

I'm a bit surprise it does compile actually.
I would have expected complains (on instantiation of C) because i implemented only one of the abstract base methods. (Even though they have the same name.)

Does this work like i would expect (assume function f has same meaning in both bases) or are there any pitfalls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [C++ inherit from multiple base classes with the same virtual function name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398409/c-inherit-from-multiple-base-classes-with-the-same-virtual-function-name)

Comment: Please ignore the C c(); syntactic error. I meant instantiation of an object of class C, by whatever means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) strikes again (have you turned on your compiler warnings?):

```
C c();
```

is a function declaration therefore no object was constructed. Anyway there would be no ambiguity if you had declared `c` as

```
C c;
```

since the two pure virtual functions would be overridden by the most derived `C::f()`.

Ambiguity would arise if you were to write something like

```
class A
{
  public: void f() {}
};

class B
{
  public: void f() {}
};

class C : public A,B
{
public: 


};

int main() {

    C c;
    c.f(); // Need to call a base one, but which one?

}
```

> error: member 'f' found in multiple base classes of different types

Answer (score 1):

```
C c();
```

is a function declaration, not a creation of object of class `C`.

And `C c;` will still compile, because your class C's two virtual functions `f`, ( inherited from each `A` and `B` ). is overridden by single function `C::f()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `C c();` is placed inside main you are right the code would compile.

Since the methods are exactly the same in both base classes they are overriden by the definition in class C.

One pitfall I can think of would be the classic diamond problem. It could occur in case A and B were subclasses of the same Base class where the `void f()` would be implemented and not overriden afterwards. For example:

```
class Base
{
  public: void f() {/*do something*/}
};
class A : public Base {};

class B : public Base {};

class C : public A, public B {};
```

In this case if you only create the object instance in your code everything works fine until you try to call the method:

```
C c;
c.f(); // compiler error
```

Then you will get an error message about ambiguous call to `f` member.

But there is a solution for this as well (*virtual inheritance*)

You can read more about the topic for example [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/diamond-problem/).

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentioned that you can still fully qualify the member:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public: virtual void f() {  
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
  }
};

class B {
  public: virtual void f() {  
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
  }
};

class C : public A, public B { 
  public: virtual void f() {  
    std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.A::f();
    c.B::f(); 
    c.f();
}
```

Output

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP said that they only implemented one of the abstract functions, but that is not true.  If class `C` implements `f()`, then both `A` and `B` have a concrete implementations now.  And more importantly, `C` is truly polymorphic to `A` and `B`.

```
class A
{
  public: virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B
{
  public: virtual void f() = 0;
};

class C : public A,B
{
  public: virtual void f()
  { // implementation here
  }
};

C c;
c.f();   // works
A& a(c);
a.f();   // works
B& b(c);
b.f();   // works

A* aa = &c;
aa->f();   // works
B* bb = &c;
bb->f();   // works
```

The important thing to realize is that the numeric values of `aa` and `bb` (the pointers) are *NOT* equal, even though they are pointing to the same object `c`.  When `cc` is cast to a pointer of `A` or `B`, the addresses must be different because `A` and `B` have different vtables. C++ will automatically do the correct pointer arithmetic to get valid base class pointers.

If you force the cast, either through `reinterpret_cast` or casting to `void*` first, then the original type of `&c` gets lost (this is essentially type erasure).

```
A* aa = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&c);
aa->f();   // UB ! (might work accidentally if A is the first baseclass of C)
B* bb = reinterpret_cast<B*>(&c);
bb->f();   // UB ! (probably will not work. In my test, it crashes the program.)
```

This example DOES NOT WORK, and you'll probably get a seg fault or some other UB.