# Two base classes with the same pure virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a class A that was inherited from class B. So the interface of class A contains some pure virtual functions of class B and some functions of class A. Now I need to make unit tests for class A, so wanna have some interface for class A that I can mock.
So now I'm wondering if the given code is correct in C++14 and can it lead to UB:

```
class Base1 {
public:
  virtual void func() = 0;
};

class Base2 {
public:
  virtual void func() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {
public:
  void func() override { }
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.func();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. We are happy to help **if** you show that you have tried your best and got stuck. So what have you researched? Have you tried to compile this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ inherit from multiple base classes with the same virtual function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398409/c-inherit-from-multiple-base-classes-with-the-same-virtual-function-name)

Comment: @FrankS101 *almost* a dupe in the question. The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18400950/1023390) to that post definitely answers this one too.

Comment: The code compiles and runs on my machine.  It is not undefined behavior. 
 Arlo Belshee points out that mocks for unit tests is a code smell that can help improve design by eliminating the need for having a mock.

Comment: @Eljay Can you provide a link to this quote from Belshee?

Comment: @Walter • I used to work with Arlo Belshee.  He has strong (and I think good) opinions on things like agile, TDD, programming principles, et cetera.  http://arlobelshee.com/the-no-mocks-book/

Comment: @Eljay How relevant is this for C++?

Comment: I've tried to compile it and it is working. But I dunno if it UB or not.

Comment: I've already read the answer of Melebius, but it is not what I need.

Comment: @Walter • it's relevant for any language in which one does unit testing, and employs mocks.  C++ is not the friendliest language for unit testing, nor for mocks.  There's another position on unit testing in general by James Coplien (who is eminently familiar with C++), in his essay "Why Most Unit Testing is Waste" -- not my position, but interesting and I have tons of respect for James.  Personally, I wish C++ had good contract support like D does.

Comment: @Eljay That the code compiles and runs on your machine does **not** mean it's not UB, actually that behavior is included in the concept of UB.

Comment: @skyking • I did not mean that *because* the code compiles & runs on my machine, it is not undefined behavior.  I was stating the OP's code is not undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this code is well-formed and `void func()` overrides both `A::func()` and `B::func()`. From the C++14 standard:

> [class.virtual]
>
> 2. If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a
>      `class Base` and in a `class Derived`, derived directly or indirectly
>      from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name,
>      parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or
>      absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also
>      virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides
>      `Base::vf`.

Comment: @EdvardDavtyan If this answers your question, you should accept it (the green tick)