# How can I override same method name from multiple bases if the return type differs?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have these two base classes:

```
struct A { virtual int fun() = 0; };
struct B { virtual long fun() = 0; };
```

I'd like to write a `struct C` that inherits from both and provides *different* overrides for both `fun`s. Obviously the following wouldn't work:

```
struct C : A, B {
    int fun() override;
    long fun() override;
};
```

I can work around this by introducing intermediate bases that redirect the calls to different names:

```
template <typename DERIVED>
struct MixinA : A {
    int fun() override {
        return static_cast<DERIVED*>(this)->int_fun();
    }
};
// Similar MixinB with long_fun

struct C : MixinA<C>, MixinB<C> {
    int int_fun();
    long long_fun();
};
```

Is there a better way? Could I somehow specify which base's `fun` I'm overriding when declaring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ inherit from multiple base classes with the same virtual function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398409/c-inherit-from-multiple-base-classes-with-the-same-virtual-function-name)

Comment: No, because the return type is different.

Comment: True, but as far as I can tell from the answer, it's going to be the same for this case.

Comment: In the question you linked, there's just one override, `void foo()`, that will be called from either base. That can't work for me because the return type is different.

Comment: No, I don't believe there's a better way (than intermediate classes) in standard C++. The answer @cigien pointed you to uses the same technique.

Comment: It looks like the answer is "There's no better way. Give them different names or use intermediate bases." I'd accept such an answer.